# Does Link Function in Directive Run via Routing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been Googling around for a while and I haven't been able to find a direct answer.

If I had a file structure for a Todo app like this:

```
app.js
index.html
 -- Todo
  | -- todo.html
  | -- todoModule.js
  | -- todoController.js
  | -- todoDirective.js
 -- Routes
  | -- routes.js
```

And in `todoDirective.js` I had:

```
myApp.directive('todoDirective', [function() {
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log('todo directive');
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: link,
        templateUrl: 'todo.html'
    };
}])
```

And in `routes.js` I had:

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) { 'use strict';
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/todo',
            controller: 'todoController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
}]);
```

Am I correct in thinking that I will see 'todo directive' output to the console?

I have a larger application I'm working on and recently found that I could not seem to access the DOM from a given directives link function. Do I have a misconception as to how Angular works?

Any insight you could give would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

directives link/controller is executed when the instance of it is created on the html page. it has nothing to do with the route.

if the template attached with route e.g. `'/todo.html'` contains an directive element then it will run its link/controller functions...

Comment: So if I put `<todo-directive></todo-directive>` in `todo.html` the link function would run?